# AWS RDS I/O request

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, iot, amazon-rds

I am having a hard time understanding the Read Operations (Count/Second) in AWS RDS monitoring.

I tried to insert around 20000 values to a table using a loop and it gave me a value of 1000 Write Operations (Count/Second) for the last one minute.

When I try to run a select statement 20000 times, I am getting only 1 Read Operation(Count/Second) for the last one minute.

Someone please explain.

Answer (score 0):

These are i/o operations on the Volumes. Seems on the select you are hitting cache 19,999 times, on write your inserts get bundled into writes. On EBS single write operations can be rather large. Read more about it [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-io-characteristics.html).

> IOPS are a unit of measure representing input/output operations per second. The operations are measured in KiB, and the underlying drive technology determines the maximum amount of data that a volume type counts as a single I/O. I/O size is capped at 256 KiB for SSD volumes and 1,024 KiB for HDD volumes

Comment: Does that mean, if I perform 20000 different select statements, I might get a larger number ? Something around 800~1000 ??

Comment: possibly, yes, if you are querying for data that is not in any cache yet

Comment: I tried a loop on a table containing a sequence of numbers.  I just tried to select one row at a time incrementing the numbers. For example select * from checking where number = 1;    select * from checking where number = 2;  select * from checking where number = 3; etc.,  I am looping till 20000. Even then I am getting only 1 read operation (count/sec). Someone please explain!